# IPointerHandler working in some cases but not others

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm building a card game and I'm using `IPointerEnterHandler` to detect when the mouse is over a card. It works for some cards but not others. It's using the exact same code and everything.

Here's the code:

```
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GlowEnabled = true;
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GlowEnabled = false;
}
```

And here's pictures of the issue.
How it's supposed to work:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And Here's where it isn't working:

[image]

[image]

And here's the unity setup:

[image]

The monsters and special cards down for the enemy and the player are the same, literally copy pasted and rotated. The code for the glow is on each of the cards and placements. Any advice would be helpful.

Edit:
I checked to make sure there was nothing in front and there isn't
[image]

Comment: Before you say it's not working, put `Debug.Log` inside `OnPointerEnter` and see if that's being called. Also make sure that this script is attache to **each** GameObject you want to detect mouse over on

Comment: Could there be anything obscuring the cards where it doesnt work?

Comment: The debug.log doesn't get called, and there isn't anything in front that I can tell

Comment: Like I said above, make sure that this script is attache to **each** GameObject you want to detect mouse over on. Not just one. All of them.

Comment: Yeah, it is, the fact that the placeholders are there proves that (the script switches them to the placeholder you see on the fields)

Comment: What render mode is the Canvas set to?

Comment: Screen Space - Camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. It turns out the cards were rotated backwards. Upon rotating the right way again they worked fine.

Comment: This is why I build out things programmatically, rather than by hand.